# Coalesce in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, coalesce

How to coalesce a table in oracle and What is it's syntax ?

Comment: There are a number of possible interpretations of your question.    Please explain in more detail.  You want people to invest their time answering your question; the least you could do is spend some of your own time to frame it properly.

Comment: Coalesce, the ANSI function, Explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108950/can-nvl-function-be-cascaded

Comment: I think it is enough explanatory and simple. I have deleted thousand of records from my table and now i want to  coalesce that table only.

Comment: Agreed with APC. user269484, just off the top of my head I can think of two different applications of the term "coalesce" in Oracle - the `COALESCE` function, and `COALESCE` when altering an index.

Comment: Agreed again.  Your question is framed as "how to coalesce a table", whereas as what you really mean is "how do I free up space occupied by a table after deleting thousands of rows".  If you had said this in the first place you would have got a suitable answer much quicker. The word "coalesce" means "to unite so as to form one mass", not "make smaller"!

Answer (score 4):

I originally suspected that you were asking about coalescing tablespaces:

```
alter tablespace mytablespace coalesce;
```

This combines contiguous extents into larger extents.  See [Oracle 10G Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3002.htm#i2093894)

But now I think perhaps what you are looking for is

```
alter table mytable shrink space compact;
```

Thiis described in detail in [this Oracle Magazine article](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-may/o35tuning.html).

Comment: I do not want to coalesce the whole tablespace, i just need to coalesce one table only.

Comment: The comments here may help: http://p2p.wrox.com/oracle/19758-oracle-8i-alter-table-table-coalesce-partition.html

Comment: @usernnn, see my revised answer.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

`coalesce` is a function that takes two (or more) parameters and return the first that is not null.

Given a table with a nullable column called, say, `Age`, you could write the following:

```
select coalesce(Age, 18) from MyTable;
```

Comment: what's the difference between this use of the function coalesce and the NVL function?
Thanks - Jay

Comment: @Jay: `COALESCE()` is portable -- it's part of the ANSI standard.

Comment: @Jay - besides what Adam says `COALESCE()` takes any number of parameters whereas `NVL()` takes only the two.

Comment: The most important difference, imho, is COALESCE is short-circuited and NVL is not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you'll need to:

```
ALTER TABLE blah MOVE TABLESPACE different-tablespace;
```

then move it back:

```
ALTER TABLE blah MOVE TABLESPACE original-tablespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) is very clear on explaining how we use COALESCE.